# Multiple Layers in Geoserver

Tags: geoserver, layers

I have a problem with Geoserver with multiple layers. At the moment the idea is to print a map of Europe, then paint 3 layers on top of this to get 3 different values matches up in a polygon. However the color and font are changing because on the layers being painted on top of eachother. Is there an easy solution to make all fonts and colors the same even when painting multiple layers on top of each other?

Thanks in advance!

Picture of what I mean: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6kb2.jpg

Comment: So you are stacking three vector layers above a raster map of Europe? Fonts and colors shouldn't change because of this, do you really use the same SLD-styling for all vector layers?

Comment: Yes I'm using the exact same layout vectors for all of them:     <CssParameter name="font-family">Times</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="font-size">16</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="font-style">normal</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="font-weight">normal</CssParameter>

Comment: Would you mind sharing your SLD-file somewhere? Maybe there is some other error in there. Also, these two links might help you along (if you don't already know them): [Polygon styling](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld-cookbook/polygons.html) and [text styling](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld-reference/textsymbolizer.html).